# I'm copying if-then statements, with slight variations... and I shouldn't have to

Tags: scripting

I know there's a better way to do this, I'm just not looking in the correct place to figure it out.

I have a *number* of these type of statements (say 1-100, or a list of different filenames).  Basically, I'm doing checks on all of them and then doing the same type of command to them.

```
if [ -f ~/file1 ]; then 
    if [ -f ~/Backup/file1 ]; then 
       rm ~/file1;
       # Someday, maybe put a filesize or filedate check as well (investigate eval)
    else
       cp -ip ~/file1 ~/Backup/file1;
       rm ~/file1;
   fi
fi
```

There should be some way to make this a function (loop once thru with file1, then do it again with file2, etc), and not have to copy-and-paste this stuff over and over and over again.

I'd like to get something that's clear-ish to newbies, since once I get this working I probably won't look at it again for 5 years, and when I do come back to it, I'll probably have forgotten everything that's not fairly clear.  This does have the virtue of being clear in what's going on :P

I've read some code which does this, said, "Hmm, that's interesting, when I need to do more than 3-4 if-thens, I should use that."  And then promptly didn't write it down..

---

Some of these files are: filename001, filename002,... filename100.

I also have the same problem for specifically named files, in which case I'd really like to iterate through a list of filenames, and just add new filenames to the list (instead of copy-and-pasting code).

I'm not looking to input anything via the commandline, everything will be laid out in the script (so I can test it, and so I can not screwup and typo something I didn't mean to type).  The idea of a datafile that lists each filename one to a line, that the script calls is interesting to me - but I'm not sure how to make that work.  Got a link?

---

> Because this can be a *lot* easier - and more efficient.

I know it can be, but it also has to be clear to people who don't program (namely me, in 5 years - when I'm starting from a point where I don't really know how to program, and will have forgotten a lot of things by the time that rolls around (if it doesn't get handed off to someone else)).  I basically take things I can understand and monkey with them until I can I misuse them to my purposes.  Right now, my scripts don't need to be very efficient, since computers are fast enough for the types of things I'm doing.

---

If backup file exists, then I'm just deleting the current file (if *it* exists - if it doesn't, I want the script to continue onto the next possibility). If backup doesn't exist, I'm copying current file (hopefully if I run overquota or something (other things may be making/sucking up quota during the time of copying) it will just bail with an error, and not have deleted anything unrecoverable) then deleting the current file.

I wouldn't mind adding in something(s) to test if the backup file is useful: timestamp (which one is newer?), size (which one is bigger?), hash (did file copy completely and correctly?) - but that's not necessary right now.

Comment: `f=file1; [ -f ~/"$f" ] && [ -f ~/Backup/"$f" ] && rm ~/"$f"` maybe also like `( rm ~/"$f" 3<~/"$f" 4< ~/Backup/"$f" ) || cp ~/"$f" ~/Backup/"$f"`

Comment: Wait - you're doing 100 `if file[1-100]; then if...`?

Comment: As mikeserv's 1st comment indicates it's easy to modify your script so that it takes the base file name as a variable rather than having it hard-wired into the code. And as his 2nd comment suggests, if the file names follow some pattern we can automate things even further. So _do_ the filenames follow a pattern? Do you want to be able to specify multiple names on the command line (or maybe even in a text file, one filename per line) so that your script can process them all, one by one?

Comment: By the efficiency thing I just meant you could roll it up into a single `tar` statement or - as I vaguely recall is possible - even just with GNU `cp`. Definitely `rsync` will do it - and probably in a fairly straightforward manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you're looking for a loop, I think.

```
cd ~; i=1000; set --
until [ "$((i+=1))" -gt 1100 ]
do    _i=${i#1}
      if    [ -f ./file"$_i" ] && 
            [ -f ./Backup/file"$_i" ]
      then  rm ./file"$_i"
      else  set -- ./file"$_i" "$@"
      fi
done
[ "$#" -gt 0 ]                  &&
cp -ip "$@" ./Backup  &&
rm "$@"
```

That will count up to 100 and handle files between `file[001-100]`. It builds an array of files needing copying and does the `cp -ip` at once, at loop close as necessary. You can do the same with `rm` as well, in fact, if you opted to use a named array rather than the shell array.

It is zero-padding the iterator up to 100 *(where the initial `-gt` evaluation cuts it off)*, but, as written, the script could be fairly easily modified to handle file numbers up to 999.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  Just wanted you to know that I changed the post, since I'd replaced the 'mv' with a 'cp' (to preserve datestamps) so I'd forgotten to add an ending 'rm', which wasn't there when you answered this question (and you might wish to edit your answer so anyone else coming through later sees a complete answer).  ie: not your fault. :)

Comment: @anon3202 - I added the `rm`,  I believe. I also edited it to handle the zero-padding for your filenames - though I'm still unclear on what *filename* should be. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: @anon3202 - wait a minute - are you always `rm`ing your file anyway? Why all the testing? Do you only want to `cp` the file if it is newer? Is that the idea here? Because this can be a *lot* easier - and more efficient.

Comment: *filename* is different for different scripts.  I can change *filename* all by myself :D  If backup file exists, then I'm just deleting the current file (I wouldn't mind adding in something to test if the backup file is useful: timestamp, size, hash - but that's not necessary right now).  If backup doesn't exist, I'm copying current file (hopefully not running overquota or anything) then deleting the current file.

Comment: Can you explain how you're doing the 0 padding?  I think it's in: _i=${i#1} but I'm unclear.  I see that you're starting with 1000 and going to 1100, but where are you removing the first two digits?

Comment: @anon3202 - the only reason I didn't glob it like `set -- ./filename[01][0-9][0-9]` was that all of the tests led me to believe the files might not actually be there. To test for newer mod times you just do basically what you already do like `[ ~/file1 -nt ~/Backup/file1 ]` which will work in most shells. I remove only the first digit - and you're right , that's where I do it. I set `$_i` to the value of the iterator sans the first 1.